# Как подсчитать сколько в строке БД не NULL значений?

Tags: php

```
for($count =1; $count<8; $count++)
{
    $tmp = mysql_query("select * FROM testProc3");
    if (is_null(mysql_result($tmp,$i,'otv'.$count)))
        ++$svet;
}
```

Так работает нестабильно

Answer (score 1):

Еще бы. Вы собственный код прочитайте — Вы каждую итерацию цикла вытаскиваете все содержимое таблицы.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testProc3 LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$non_null_cnt = 0;
for (var $i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
    if (!is_null($row["otv$i"])) { $non_null_cnt += 1; }
}
```

Если бы в массиве не содержалось других ключей, кроме otv1...otv7 — можно было бы обойтись `count($row) - count(array_filter($row, "is_null"))`.

Comment: > Если бы в массиве не содержалось других ключей, кроме otv1...otv7 — можно было бы обойтись

Собственно:

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT otv1, otv2, otv3, otv4, otv5, otv6, otv7 FROM testProc3 LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $non_null_cnt = count($row) - count(array_filter($row, "is_null"));

Comment: Так-то оно так, но в [соседнем вопросе](http://hashcode.ru/questions/110997/) видно, что он должен выбирать не только эти колонки.

Хотя если остальные колонки строго `NOT NULL`, то `7 - count(array_filter($row, "is_null"))` будет давать правильный результат.

Answer (score 1):

Мало того, что запрос не надо делать в цикле (а перед циклом) так и в запросе не надо грузить всю таблицу, а только удовлетворяющие условию:

```
SELECT * FROM testProc3 WHERE otv1 IS NOT NULL AND otv2 IS NOT NULL ...
```

Таким образом в цикле обработки не нужно будет проверять пиэйчпишной is_null

А вот саму строку запроса можно сформировать в цикле пхп, если заранее не известно количество "ответов" - otv1, otv2, ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$expresions = array();
for (range(1, 7) as $n) {
    $expresions[] = "CASE WHEN otv$n IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END";
}

$sql = "SELECT id, ".implode(' + ', $expresions)." AS cnt FROM testProc3";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    printf("Row #%d has %d not null fields\n", $row['id'], $row['cnt']);
}
```